# Rename main.js on angular build to something else then main.js

Tags: angular, webpack, build, configuration, filenames

Is there a way to configure the Angular build to give the file it is creating another name? Not `main.js` but `foo.js`. I tried to find something expecting that i can configure it in the angular.json or wirh a webpack config, but could not find anything on it. This is the first time i have to change something. In the past i just worked with the default config that gets created when create a Project.